# Stuck at "Erase disk and install Ubuntu"

Tags: 16.04, system-installation

I am trying to install Ubuntu from a USB key on my laptop.
Boot and selecting language goes well.

When I get to "Erase disk and install Ubuntu" I click on "continue", select a drive to erase (/dev/sda), click on "Install Now". It loads the same window, only the title has changed (now is "Installation type"). Click again on install now (with same drive selected).

[Erase disk and install Ubuntu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oT6rq.jpg)

It brings me back to the first window where my only choices are "Erase disk and install Ubuntu" and "Something else" (to manually do it). And the only action I can do are "continue" or "back".

So I'am trapped in a loop, anyone as a clue on where the problem comes from?

I got the same problem with iso 14.04 and 16.04 (notice that I already managed to install Fedora and Debian on this laptop)

Thanks and have a good day!

EDIT:adding screenshot

Screenshot of "Something Else"

[Trying to create a partition table in Something else](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLGNz.jpg)

And clicking on Install now in "Something else" returns "no root file system"

Comment: How did you burn the ISO to the USB drive?

Comment: Add screenshots if possible

Comment: What happens when you go to 'Something Else'? Does it let you proceed with your installation?

Comment: I used Rufus on Windows to burn the ISO

Comment: Use UUI @vemonet to make bootable usb..rufus sometimes do such things

Comment: Any resolution to this problem ?

Answer (score 2):

Your best course of action is probably to run [wipefs](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/wipefs.8.html) on the drive manually before starting the Ubuntu install process.

The automated Ubuntu install process, by default, works very hard to preserve data and avoid accidental OS erasures that plagued early Linux installers and soured new users to the Linux experience.

Sometimes, if a disk has an exotic or unusual partitioning or formatting, the install process can get hung up. In your case, the disk seems to be part of an LVM group, so the installer may be trying to make sure it isn't damaging a disk that is part of a disk set.

Was the drive pulled from a RAID array or another multi-disk set? Those kinds of disks tend to present corner cases that standard, friendly installers may not cope well with. Manually clear the drive and try the install again, or engage the Ubuntu installer team to see if you can locate the bug.

To start down the rabbit hole of bug submission, check the [install logs](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/s390x/ch05s03.html) in **/var/log** and **/var/log/installer** by opening a terminal window <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F1-6</kbd> with the username "ubuntu" and no password. You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F7</kbd> to return to the GUI.